# opencv create circle out of bounds

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, graphics, geometry

I am trying to create a function that adds a random circle on an image. The circle should not pass the boundaries of the image. I tried it this way:

```
def create_circle(image):
  found = False
  color = (np.random.randint(low=0, high=255),
           np.random.randint(low=0, high=255),
           np.random.randint(low=0, high=255))
  while not found:
    pos = (np.random.randint(low=0, high=image.shape[1]),
           np.random.randint(low=0, high=image.shape[0]))
    rad = np.random.randint(low=0, high=image.shape[0]//2)
    if( rad +pos[0]< image.shape[0] and rad +pos[1]< image.shape[1]
       and rad -pos[0] >= 0 and rad -pos[1]>= 0):
      found = True
  cv2.circle(image,pos,rad,color,-1)
```

the circle keep getting out of the image boundaries

[image]

Comment: Possibly you need to put the cv2.circle() inside the if, so that it gets drawn only when found = True. So indent it below found = True

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a small error in the logic for deciding if the generated position and radius are valid. The conditions

```py
rad - pos[0] >= 0 and rad - pos[1] >= 0
```

are equivalent to

```py
rad >= pos[0] and rad >= pos[1]
```

Which is `True` only if the radius exceeds both the `x` and `y` coordinate of the center of the circle. You want the opposite, i.e.

```py
pos[0] >= rad and pos[1] >= pos[1]
# or
pos[0] - rad >= 0 and pos[1] - rad >= 0
```

Which will evaluate `True` only if both the `x` and `y` coordinates of the center of the circle exceed the radius.